# How to center align text in CDateTimeCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc, text-formatting

I'm using `CDateTimeCtrl` in my dialog application. Now we have already agreed with the client about the size of the `CDateTimeCtrl`. The 1st problem is, it is by default left-aligned, and is really close to the left border. The 2nd problem is it leaves a really wide space on the right side of the control. Hence, the solution to solve both problems would be to center align text.

Unfortunately, in the Properties window, there is no alignment property (except for "Right align" in which there were no changes when I tried to toggle it).

Now, I've tried calling `CWnd::ModifyStyle` in the `OnInitDialog()` event. Also, no luck with this.

For the actual code,

```
auto timePicker = (CDateTimeCtrl*)GetDlgItem(IDC_TIME_PICKER);
timePicker->ModifyStyle(0, SS_CENTER);

return TRUE; // this function is the OnInitDialog()
```

What could I be missing that calling this function does not center the text of `CDateTimeCtrl`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a style that is suited for a static control and use the style in a date time control.

All available styles are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/date-and-time-picker-control-styles).

The control itself also doesn't have child controls. It draw the values itself.
Maybe there is a chance to subclass the control and overwrite the `WM_PAINT` message and doing a kind of ownerdrawing by yourself.

I don't use the date time picker and I confess: I don't like it at all. I wrote a complete own control that is much more flexible.